# Magento promotion is being disable after a day

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm setting a promotion in my Magento store, to do it I go to *`"Promotions" -> "Catalog Price Rules" -> "New".`*

It looks fine for certain time but after (something like) a day that promotions is not being displayed in the sopping cart or any product detail screen.

Am I missing something? I haven't fount anything about this problem. Why is it getting misconfigured?

```
Magento version: 1.9.1.1
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: there are plenty question about magento in stack overflow, also you can find magento tags when you ask a question... so your comment doesn't make any sense

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are Magento questions on SO already. The link I gave clearly stated what was on-topic and not. Unless a question is about programming it is off-topic. My comment makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if your cron is not running.

As everyday cron runs it will process rules and accordingly updates price for dates.
If its not run then code will not find discounted price which in turn will result in logical issues as stated in your post.

Comment: How can I start running my "cron"?

Comment: add cron.php to be executed by your server every 5 minutes or every 15 minutes.Cron xml tabs have cron scheduled for different activities.just setting cron.php will do.

Comment: I think I have it set up

Comment: Does the issue still prevail.

Comment: Yes, maybe I have my cron misconfigured ?

Comment: Check your data base table and see if dates are present dates or past dates in price index tables.Also you can check cron schedule table to get some idea.

Comment: I'll check it and let you know